# What is the JSON syntax to add tags to a statusupdate in IBM Connections?

Tags: json, opensocial, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I want to post (programmatically) a statusupdate to the activitystream in IBM Connections (4.0). I am looking for the correct place to put this JSON

```
"tags":[{"objectType":"tag","displayName":"ibms"}],
```

I have tried this:

```
{

"actor": {

"id": "@me"

},

"verb": "post",

"title": "${share}",



"content":"This event is my <i>second entry</i> #ibms",

"updated": "2013-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",

"object": {

"summary": "First Entry details #ibms",

"tags":[{"objectType":"tag","displayName":"ibms"}],

"objectType": "note",

"id": "objectid5",

"displayName": "First entry",

}

}
```

And the entry is posted succesfully, but the tags are not there, I am looking for a sample that correctly posts a note to the activitystream containing tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can add tags to status updates.  At least you don't seem to be able to in the Connections UI so I don't see why you would be able to programmatically.  I believe you should be using the [micro-blogging API](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.0%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Posting_microblog_entries_ic45&content=pdcontent) to post status updates.

Comment: Yes it works with ublog, very easy (twitter like). Would you know if I can ublog to a community ?

Comment: I don't believe so, since you can't microblog to a communities feed specifically

Comment: Ok, so that rules out creating a statusupdate in a community with tags ?

Answer (score 3):

On the question of posting a status update to a community just replace the @me in /ublog/@me/@all with the id of the community in question and post as usual. e.g.

```
/connections/opensocial/rest/ublog/urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:communities.community:7ee13563-a7d6-41f1-9fdb-e7eb979900e4/@all
```

You do need to have rights to Post to the community needless to say.

Answer (score 0):

I know activity streams has some suggested base extensions, as indicated here.
http://activitystrea.ms/head/activity-schema.html#tags-property

```
   "tags": [
        {
        "objectType": "person",
        "displayName": "John"
      },
      {
        "objectType": "person",
        "displayName": "Jane"
      }
    ]
```

As in the following example

```
{
            "provider": {
                "id": "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn",
                "displayName": "IBM Connections - News Service",
                "url": "https://greenhouse.lotus.com/news"
            },
            "generator": {
                "image": {
                    "url": "https://greenhouse.lotus.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.oneui3.styles/imageLibrary/Icons/ComponentsGray/ProfilesGray16.png?etag=20130711.110413"
                },
                "id": "profiles",
                "displayName": "IBM Connections - Profiles",
                "url": "https://greenhouse.lotus.com/profiles"
            },
            "actor": {
                "objectType": "person",
                "id": "@me",
                "displayName": "Paul Bastide"
            },

            "title": "Test from Paul",
            "object": {
                "summary": "TTest",
                "objectType": "note",
                "author": {
                    "connections": {
                        "state": "active"
                    },
                    "objectType": "person",
                    "id": "urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:profiles.person:9f9c3740-88ed-102b-9b41-bfd8328767c1",
                    "displayName": "Paul"
                },
                "id": "urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:profiles.note:74b5fd86-3a1d-4f11-93a2-8a771d9e877e",
                "likes": {
                    "totalItems": 0
                },

            },
            "verb": "post",
"tags": [
      {
        "objectType": "person",
        "displayName": "John"
      },
      {
        "objectType": "person",
        "displayName": "Jane"
      }
    ]
        }
```

Perhaps add it under the context as well...

Comment: A first try, does not give the desired result, if you specify objectType : "tag" in stead of "person" does it still work ?

Comment: are you on 4.5? or 4.0? I tried with 4.5  whoops, I didn't try with another object